# My React application failed to compile strapi sdk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, strapi

I am done writing  my application but to build it is an issue, it just keep  giving me this error:

Creating an optimized production build.

[image]

Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file:

```
./node_modules/strapi-sdk-javascript/build/main/lib/sdk.js:16
```

Answer (score 0):

the simply answer is to update the react-scripts to the latest version

> **sudo npm install --save react-scripts@latest**

then build the program

[image]